# python discord bot: How to have the bot copy your input and repeat it in chat?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a Discord bot that is not acting the way I want it to.

What I want to happen is the following.

> me:^say hello how are you
>
> *bot deletes previous message*
>
> bot: hello how are you

This is my code but so far it doesn't work and I haven't even gotten to the delete message part.

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def say(ctx):
        split = client.split(" ")
        message = str(split[2])
        await client.say(message)
```

Imports and relevant information.

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import random
    import os
    import asyncio
    import time`

    prefix = "^"
    dclient = discord.Client()
    client = commands.Bot(description="Ello", command_prefix=prefix)
    sleep = time.sleep`
```

me: ^say hello how are you

|what i want|

bot:*deletes commanding message*

bot: hello how are you

|what i get|

bot:*nothing*

error > pastebin.com/CysFmj06

Comment: Would you add more details about the issue you are facing, please? What do you get instead of what you want?

Comment: me: ^say hello how are you

|what i want|

bot:*deletes commanding message*

bot: hello how are you

|what i get|

bot:*nothing*

error >

https://pastebin.com/CysFmj06

Comment: You should add this to your question. It is unreadable in its current format.

Comment: did that btw...

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the bot to have the "Manage Messages" Permission, but as for the code:

```
    @bot.command()
    async def say(ctx, *, arg):
      await ctx.message.delete()
      await ctx.send(arg)
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

For deleting messages the bot needs "Manage Messages" permission.

```
   @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def say(ctx):
        msg = ctx.message.content.split(" ", 1)
        await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
```